# Where should the fileset property be placed within the ant build file?

Tags: ant

Here is an example of my beginning build file, I do not know where to put the fileset property. Right now I have a build.properties file that defines src as my directory with the current src. Ex(src= C:\workspace\project\src)

My fileset is defined like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">


   <fileset dir="${src}" 
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
   </fileset>

 <target name="info">
  <echo>packaging the .java files...</echo>
</target>

</project>
```

I don't really understand where the .java files are supposed to be put. this is only for my understanding and a demo. can I include them in a random folder?? Is the fileset located in the proper placement or should it be inside the target task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your build file the following error is thrown.

```
$ ant -p
Buildfile: build.xml
build.xml:6: Element type "fileset" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

This not related to the placement of the fileset tag, but rather a message telling you your xml is not well formed.

Fix the XML as follows:

```
   <fileset dir="${src}">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
   </fileset>
```

Note the missing ">" character.

Comment: thank you MArk, one more question, do you know what is specifically happening with the include .java files. where are they being sent to? Do I need to add another target folder? As of right now the buildfile is working. just don't know where the files are being added to.

Comment: @camel-man A fileset declared at the top of your build file without an "id" attribute is pretty useless. The "id" enables it to referenced by other tasks elsewhere in the build.